# 22 year old indoor palm - dying or dead?

Tags: trees, palm

[image: Tall potted palm with all brown leaves]

Can this tree be revived?  I see hope in a new green frond at the top but it has looked like this for two months now.  I think my husband traumatized the trunk when we moved it from one room to another.  The soil is wet and has been wet for two months.
Should I remove the dead fronds?

Comment: Looks rather dim, and what do you mean by "traumatized the trunk" (I don't see any obvious damage.)

Answer (score 2):

The small trunk on the right appears to be dead with the symptom being the vertical areas of shrinkage at the base. I would cut that back to the base.

For situations like this where the plant has been stressed I usually recommend cutting it back. However palms do not regrow from the top of the stem if cut back.  The best you could hope for is a new stem sprouting from the base.

This appears to be a bamboo palm, or [Chamaedorea seifrizii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamaedorea) which can spread by runners to form a clump.

I recommend:

- verify the plant is not sitting in water, if it is drain it and do not water
- move to the highest light possible, right next to a window
- remove the dead foliage by cutting it as it joins the stem so you can see if new growth occurs
- wait.......a month or even two months for signs of new growth at the top
- water sparingly and only when the top few inches of soil is dry
- if new growth is not seen your last resort is cutting all the stems back to the base and hope for new growth from a runner in another month or so

Comment: Sincerest thanks for the detailed reply!  I'm going to take these steps and do a lot of praying!  Thank you again!